# Is there a way to set the sort order of each element returned in a linq select within the query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ select query which fetches a list of books:

```
var books = from b in _context.Books
            where b.Available && b.BookType == bookType
            orderby b.Title
            select new BookViewModel
            {
                Title = b.Title,
                Description = b.Description,
                Id = b.Id,
                SortOrder = ?
            };
```

`BookViewModel` has a `SortOrder` property which I want to set in the query. The first book in the list would have `SortOrder = 1`, the second book would have 2, etc. It's essentially just the index of the book in the returned list.

Is there a way to set this within the query? I understand I could do another linq query once I have the list, but this seems inefficient. I don't properly understand the innards of a linq select, but given it's sorted by the orderby I don't see why there wouldn't exist some way to set the index of the element.

Comment: @Stackberg `SortOrder` is not part of the Book entity it's a value the OP wants to calculate based on the results of the query.

Comment: You just need to use the LINQ method syntax instead of query syntax. With that, you can use the `Select()` overload that gives you the index of the enumerated value. See marked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @PeterDuniho, though I can't seem to find anything in the linked duplicate that talks specifically about the `.Select((x, index) =>` syntax that Rufus' answer explains.

Comment: Look at the highest-voted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11437562 (though, you could use the accepted answer too, just follow its advice and use your own indexer when enumerating the orderby results, to create the final select for `BookViewModel`)

Comment: Ah, it was linked to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908029/linq-to-sql-orderby-thenby) when I saw it marked as duplicate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `Select` statement, you can select both the `index` and the `item`, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
var books = _context.Books
    .Where(book => book.Available && book.BookType == bookType)
    .OrderBy(book => book.Title)
    .ToList()
    .Select((book, index) => new BookViewModel
    {
        Title = book.Title,
        Description = book.Description,
        Id = book.Id,
        SortOrder = index + 1
    });
```

Comment: I think the OP actually would want `SortOrder = index + 1` to get the first book to have a `SortOrder` of 1 if the magnitude actually matters.

Comment: @juharr Thanks! Updated sample.

Comment: Sweet, this is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It turns out including index in the select called on `IOrderedQueryable` is not supported: `This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select' is currently not supported.` I'll have to find an alternative solution. Unfortunately there are no answers for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427440/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-an-item-in-an-iorderedqueryable) .

Comment: I'm not at my computer, but does calling `ToList()` resolve the issue? It should force the database query to execute and return the items, which can then be accessed by index. See edited sample above.

Comment: Nice, that works, thanks. It's annoying that there has to be an extra performance hit by calling `ToList()`, but I guess if accessing the index on an `IQueryable` were possible it would be doing something like that under the hood anyway.

Comment: It turns out that calling `.ToList()` in the middle of the query like that results in a massive performance hit. I've decided to just call `ToList()` after the select and then loop through and set `SortOrder` for each element.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.